# Where should I put the previous predicted sequence in LSTM for optical character recognition systems

Tags: ocr, lstm

I am trying to build an optical character recognition system that can recognize handwritten sentences using the LSTM cell.

Now what I have understood from literature is that you need to give two inputs to the LSTM cell: one is the image that you are trying to recognize and the second is the sequence of words it has already predicted. So for example if I had an image that read "I love machine learning", I would create the following pairs of input:

- Image + startseq
- Image + startseq + I
- Image + startseq + I + love

So for each input you want the LSTM to predict the next word i.e. I, love, machine for the above sequences.

The problem that I'm having is that I can't figure out how to input the image AND the previous sequence to the LSTM cell. Do I divide my image (a 2-D matrix) into row/column vectors and send them to the LSTM one at a time and after I'm done with that I send in the previous sequence of words? But this way I'll have quite long input sequences which might lead to large converging times.

I know image captioning tasks vectorize input images using pretrained neural nets but can that be done for optical character recognition systems, i.e. would that cause accuracy issues?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you don't have to feed recognized words back into LSTM. You only feed an input (feature) sequence and the LSTM learns to propagate relevant information through this sequence.

You should think of input sequence and output sequence when talking about Recurrent Neural Networks (RNNs).
The input to a RNN at time-step t is:

- state of memory cell at t-1
- input element at t

LSTM has a more advanced internal structure than a vanilla RNN to allow more robust training. But from a user perspective, it works just like a vanilla RNN. You input a sequence and LSTM computes a output sequence for you.

When doing handwriting recognition, you usually extract a feature sequence from the input image (e.g. by using convolutional layers).
Then, you feed this feature sequence into LSTM layers.
You map the output sequence to a character-probability matrix which is then decoded into the final text by the CTC layer.

Here is a short tutorial how to build a handwriting recognition system, it should give you an idea of which data (see "Data": "CNN output" and "RNN output") flows into LSTM and which data flows out of LSTM:
https://towardsdatascience.com/2326a3487cd5